# hardcoded navidation bar vs ajax

Tags: ajax, database, web, loading

I have quite big navigation bar (300kb) which makes it work slow
Just wondering what would be better,

1. use hardcoded version and update it weekly? (In this way I don't query a database, but client s
   pends time waiting while it loads)
2. Use Ajax for 3rd level of submenus.
   Website site will be small which s good. And for clients who can't use ajax still be a way to use nav bar up to 2nd level. (That's fine). But I'm kinda worried that I will get many requests from many users which could slow down everything because of multiple calls to database.

Which way is better?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd personally go with a SSI (server Side include) and let the database manage my navigation.

I'd assume you are on some sort of CMS so the core infrastructure should be there already.

Set your caches properly and load speed won't be a problem and will greatly reduce queries.

Instead of updating something manually just clean the cache once a week to update it, easy as pie :)